# PHP cookie, can't get integer from cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying out PHP cookies for the first time. When I try to get the value from a string it works fine, but when I try to do that with an integer it prints this error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
```

What does that mean?

**My cookie code:**

```
$CookieUserName = "demo";
$CookieUserID = 1;
setcookie($CookieUserName, $CookieUserID, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); //     86400 = 1 day
```

Show the value of cookie

**This works:**

```
 echo $CookieUserName;
```

**This doesn't:**

```
echo $CookieUserID;
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Note that these are just variables with the word "Cookie" in their name.

Comment: Why not just use sessions? You could also use $_COOKIE (is this been deprecated yet? I haven't used it in a long time hah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) takes name & value as a string. You have your value set as int. Change your $CookieUserID to string. Below works fine for me.

```
$CookieUserName = "demo";
$CookieUserID = "1";
setcookie($CookieUserName, $CookieUserID, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); //     86400 = 1 day
```